# Stop streaming responce

Tags: nginx, flask, large-language-model

In this code snipit is used to stop the streaming functionality ongoing streaming llm response, the functionality working in the local machine but when deployed in the development in the Nginx server its not working. where is the problem and how to resolve it?

```
@app.route("/v2/chat", methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    global stop_event
    data = flask_request.json
    prompt = data.get("prompt")
    memory_key = data.get("memory_key") if data.get("memory_key") is not None else str(uuid.uuid1())
    dashboard_json = data.get("data_payload")
    temperature=data.get("temperature",0.1)
    stop_event = Event()
    container = data.get("container") # Get the container name

    global memory
    res = Response(chain(prompt, dashboard_json, memory_key,temperature,stop_event), mimetype="text/event-stream")
    print(memory_key)
    res.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
    
    
    
    @app.route("/v2/stop_streaming", methods=["GET"])
@app.route("/stop_streaming", methods=["GET"])
def stop_streaming():
    try:
        stop_event.set()
        logging.info("Streaming stopped ")
        return jsonify({"message": "Streaming stopped"})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("streaming not stopped")
        return jsonify({"error": "An error occurred during stop_streaming"}), 500
```